# Logarithm equations

Tags: logarithms

It has been years since I had to take a math course.  I am currently in an advanced Computer Science course and I have been hit with a hw assignment that is bringing back all the math I used to crank out.

Can someone help me understand this question?

Show that $\log_a x = c  \log_b x$ for some constant c (expressed only in terms of the constants a
and b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly:

$$ \log_a x = c\log_b x \ \implies \ c = \frac{\log_a x}{\log_b x}$$

By the law of logarithm, $\log_a b = \frac{1}{\log_b a}$

Therefore,

$$ c = \frac{\log_x b}{\log_x a}= \log_a b$$

In the last line, I used the following result (change of base to x):

$$ \log_k h = \frac{\log_p h}{\log_p k}$$

Comment: I can only express it in terms of the constants of a and b thought right? So your first answer of c = log_a x / log_b x wouldn't count right?

Comment: The key is (using e.g. the hint below, or the rest of the derivation above): this quantity actually does *not* depend on $x$ at all. ($x$ appears in the expression, but it is misleading: the value of the ratio does not change when $x$ varies.)

Comment: @user3352075, the correct answer is $c = \log_a b$. The last line is just an explanation of what I've done.

Comment: @ClementC., absolutely correct, I've changed the $x$ to $p$ to avoid the confusion.

Comment: OK awesome thanks for breaking it down for me

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$\log_a x = \frac{\ln x}{\ln a}$, for any $x,a>0$ ($a\neq 1$).

Answer (score 0):

$$\log_a{x}=c\log_b{x}$$

But $$\log_a{x}=\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}$$ so $$\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}=c\frac{\ln x}{\ln b}$$  Therefore,  $$\frac{\ln b}{\ln a}=c\frac{\ln x}{\ln x}= c(1)$$

Your final result is:   $$c=\frac{\ln b}{\ln a}$$

Comment: Thank you for breaking it out for me.

Comment: Thanks. Please check the "accept" check mark if you're satisfied, so the question is no longer posting as 'unanswered'